# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-push

I am following this article for integrating web push notifications

https://rossta.net/blog/web-push-notifications-from-rails.html

Here is my code which i wrote in application.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Service Worker is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js')
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log('Successfully registered!', ':^)', registration);
      registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true })
      .then(function(subscription) {
        $.post("/subscribe", { subscription: subscription.toJSON() });
      });
      }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Registration failed', ':^(', error);
  });
}
```

But I am getting below error, i don't much about promises, but i am getting error at `then` statement.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?